# how to see address of a structure in printf

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a function which returns address as following

```
struct node *create_node(int data)
{
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        printf("create node temp->data=%d\n",temp->data);
        return temp;
}
```

where struct node is

```
struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};
```

How can I see in printf("") the address stored in temp?

**UPDATE**
If I check the adressed in gdb the addresses are coming in hex number format i.e.
0x602010 where as same address in `printf("%p",temp)` is coming in a different number which is different from what I saw in gdb print command.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the pointer address format specifier `%p`:

```
printf("Address: %p\n", (void *)temp);
```

Comment: +1: For overzealous (pedanticly correct) compilers, cast the pointer to `void*`: `printf("%p", (void*)temp)`

Comment: Why not just print the address of the thing, like `printf("0x%08X", &temp);`?

Comment: @aroth: you have no guarantee `unsigned` and `struct node**` have the same representation: your snippet fails terribly on 64-bit machines for instance

Comment: @pmg: I think your first comment re casting to `void *` only applies to C++ ? In C you can pass any pointer type to a function which expects a `void *`, no ?

Comment: @Paul: `printf` is a function accepting a variable number of arguments. There is "no prototype" for the parameters after the first. The compiler cannot enforce the value to be of the correct type and the programmer must do it manually. *I don't know about C++.*

Comment: @pmg I've added the (void *) cast, thanks for the nit-picking ;)

Comment: @jv42 If I check the adressed in gdb the addresses are coming in hex number format i.e.
0x602010 where as same address in `printf("%p",temp)` is coming in a different number which is different from what I saw in gdb print command.

Comment: I used `print` command on gdb when I reached that statement whose address I wanted to see. I use Ubuntu 64 bit and gcc-4.4.3

Comment: perhaps, better to add "\n". :)

Comment: @Registered: I don't get what you're saying. For me a statement has no address, not in the dynamic memory address kind we're discussing about.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** 
**Don't do this!  It prints the address of the pointer, not what you want!**

I had all kinds of trouble getting this to work, but here's something that the compiler (I use the simple "cc" unix command line) didn't complain about and seemed to give appropriate results:

```
struct node temp;
// ... whatever ...
printf ("the address is %p", &temp);
```

[Rather than deleting, I left this as an example of what NOT to do. -smb]

Comment: This is incorrect (see the other answer for discussion), also, the question clearly asks to see `temp` and not `&temp`

Comment: @M.M, yep, further tests show that you're right.  This answer prints the address of the pointer, not the value within.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

#include<stdio.h>
struct anywhere
{ 
double a;
int b;
char c;
float d;
}g;
int main()
{
printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n",&g.a,&g.b,&g.c,&g.d);
return 0
}
```

now we can get output:
address of g.a vice versa

we can print the structure variable address like this way
and also how padding happening in the structures we can see by printing the address of the each and every member.

thank you all
any mistakes and suggestions please ping comment .